# Custom control with EntityObject Collection in Property

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, entity-framework-4

What should I do to have Custom control with ICollection which can be bound to BindingSource which has datasource set to MyObjectContext.MyEntityObject which takes all MyEntityObject from database ?

Thanks for any hint,
bye